# It is good practice to use a ViewController for each ContainerView

Tags: ios

Is it a good practice to use a ViewController for each ContainerView of a SegmentedControl tab?

Comment: If your both view of segment control has large code and complex to maintain in future Yes i suggest to use container view if it has simple structure then you can use it in same view controller without container view depends on your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is depend on your requirement and UI Design structure.

- If number of subviews or controll are more in each segment, Then it is best to use a ViewController for each ContainerView of a SegmentedControl tab.
- if controll are less like one button and UITableview then i do not suggest to use above way.